# Why can't I compile GLIBC on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: gcc, glibc

I'm trying to compile the [Linux From Scratch kernel, version 7.1](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) on Ubuntu 12.04, running inside of a virtualbox.

I've worked through a part of the tutorial successfully, but when I reach Step 5.7: Building Glibc-2.14.1, I get an error when I make.

```
In file included from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syslog.c:10:0
../misc/syslog.c: In function '__vsyslog_chk':
../misc/syslog.c:144:9: warning: variable 'prioff' set but not used [-Wunused-but-
    set-variable
../misc/syslog.c:123:1: sorry, unimplemented: inlining failed in call to 'syslog':        
    function body not available.
../misc/syslog.c:155:9: sorry, unimplemented: called from here
make[2]: *** [/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/misc/syslog.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.14.1/misc'
make[1]: *** [misc/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.14.1'
make: ***[all] Error 2
```

After some googling, I saw a filed bug report:
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10375
that had the same errors I was seeing, but I couldn't divine a solution.

Any tips on where I should head?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The bug report is pretty obvious](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10375) -- see the last two posts, especially.

The problem is that (their) GLIBC is incompatible with the `FORTIFY_SOURCE` option set by default by Ubuntu's *gcc*.

The better solution is to get the latest copy from trunk, where the problem has been fixed; alternately, unset (disable) that option in the makefile or before calling `make` with:

```
export CFLAGS=-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
```

Comment: I appreciate you clearing up for me how to unset flags while using make.
My problem seemed to be just pebkac, though. Starting the tutorial again from the top (only 4 or 5 steps) managed to get me through this problem.